# How to place random value generated with Javascript to input?

Tags: javascript, input, random

I have a javascript that creates a random number and I need to place this number as a value for the input element. This is the script I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function randomNumber (00000,99999)
{
  m = parseInt(m);
  n = parseInt(n);
  return Math.floor( Math.random() * (n - m + 1) ) + m;
}
</script>
```

But actually my task is to generate a random number between 00000 and 99999 and then to post it as a value to input element. I've searched for the answer but haven't find how to place the random value...

Comment: Did you modify existing code to add the `00000` and `99999` in place of the `m` and `n` variables? The code you've posted isn't valid JS.

Comment: Yes, I'm now using the code suggested by Donovan Charpin in the answer below, but still can't make it work, the best result I get is NaN value, in other cases the value is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set an input, you can use this :

```
document.getElementById('yourInput').value = YourRandomNumber;
```

in your function <kbd>[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/4cm9x/2/)</kbd>

```
function randomNumber (m,n)
{
  m = parseInt(m);
  n = parseInt(n);
  YourRandomNumber = Math.floor( Math.random() * (n - m + 1) ) + m;
  document.getElementById('yourInput').value = YourRandomNumber;
}
```

and when you call, `randomNumber (00000,99999);`

Comment: Thanks! But it doesn't work when I just put the script in the head section, and in Jsfiddle there's onload option chosen but I don't understand how to do the same on my page.

Comment: I've found the solution yesterday with:
`<body onload="randomNumber (00000,99999)">`
Thanks again!